# Facebook headchat for windows 8.1

Tags: windows, facebook, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I m starting to create an windows 8.1 app with visual studio 13'. 
My idea is to create a simple login fb form - simple list with online/ offline friends and heads like android os when chatting with someone. 
A very simple image how i dream it: http://img.prntscr.com/img?url=http://i.imgur.com/plb2mXc.png .

My questions are: 
1) Can i keep going with this idea? I mean: Can i have permissions which i need from facebook sdk- api? 
2) Heads must be create like widgets or i have to create a bar on which leans heads chat?

Thank in advanced!!!

Answer (score 1):

Since friend permissions are gone (that would include the `friends_online_presence` permission), there is no way to build this. Check out the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: thank you for quick respond. If friends permission are gone then how can exist im apps like: Nimbuzz - digsby - trillian - Pidgin. Maybe i have to pay for this package of code and put in my form ?

Comment: they are using an old app created before end of april 2014. it will stop working for them after april 2015.